# Creating a co-authorship graph

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am analysing an author dataset and I wish I could create a co-authorship graph from this dataset. A author graph was created using CYPHER, just this way:

```
CREATE (N0{data:"2007-12-18", title:"ABC"}),
  (N2 {data:"2007-10-20",title:"BBB"}),
  (N3 {data:"2007-08-02",title:"CCC"}),
  (N4 {name:"xxx"}),
  (N5 {name:"yyy"}),
  (N6 {name:"zzz"}),
  N4-[R0:autor_de]->N0,
  N5-[R1:autor_de]->N0,
  N6-[R2:autor_de]->N2,
  N5-[R3:autor_de]->N3;
```

I can't figure out how to create a new graph so that authors were linked by a new relationship such as `"are_coauthors"`. Sorry if this is a very simple question, I know that this can solved  using Java and (maybe) py2neo, but does someone has any hint?

Answer (score 2):

In cypher you can do something like (assuming an autoindex on title):

```
start title=node:node_auto_index("title:*")
match a-[:autor_de]->title<-[:autor_de]-b
create unique a-[:coautores]-b
```

To create a link between coauthors.

Comment: Thank you [Wes Freeman](http://stackoverflow.com/users/683201/wes-freeman), it's perfect! Now, from your hint, I can make  some analysis on co-workers network. Thanks a lot!

Comment: De nada! If you don't think you'll get anything better you can accept the answer with the green checkbox to the left.

Comment: Something weird: everything was ok in web console but when I tried in neo4j-shell I got: _"Index `node_auto_index` does not exist"_, so I thought I should reindex nodes: "start n=node(*) where has(n.title) set n.title=n.title;" But as I tried to create coautores graph, just like 1. The same error...

Comment: you can do start title=node(*) ... unless you have a big graph. If you want to learn how autoindexing works, check out: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/auto-indexing.html

Comment: Ok, solved. It was needed to change configuration file changing commented line to uncommented: _node_auto_indexing=true_ Ok, thank you once more, [Wes Freeman](http://stackoverflow.com/users/683201/wes-freeman)!